# how to make <li> add css class active after refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

after clicking `li` item. i set `active` attribute to css class but `li` has a link to forward another page. active css disappear? how to do this? i have been used localstorage to cache my old selected li item. i can not find any solution. How to make alive active class setting after refreshing? how to set active class alive after refreshing page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("li").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(id);

        var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');
        if (selectedolditem != null) {

            $('#' + selectedolditem).siblings().find("active").removeClass("active");
            $('#' + selectedolditem).addClass("active");
            localStorage.clear();
            return;

        }

        $('#'+id).siblings().find("active").removeClass("active");
        $('#' + id).addClass("active");
        localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", id);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are trying to retrieve it onclick. That's the wrong logic. The correct logic is: when the page loads, retrieve it. When the `li` is clicked, store it. You also have a problem when using `find("active")`, you need to use the class character `.` otherwise it will search for elements with the tag name `active` not the class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        $('#' + id).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
            //                       ^ you forgot this
        $('#' + id).addClass("active");
        localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", id);
    });

    var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');

    if (selectedolditem != null) {
        $('#' + selectedolditem).siblings().find(".active").removeClass("active");
        //                                        ^ you forgot this
        $('#' + selectedolditem).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working for dynamic page seletion after page reload. But first page default active not working...

Answer (score 9):

Try following.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
    {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: How to make it work also for subMenuItems, if inside of one 'li' there is another 'ul', with 'li' items. The above function does not work for subMenuItems.

Answer (score 1):

**Try following.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            var currurl = window.location.pathname;
            var val=$('li:has(a[href="'+currurl+'"])').addClass('active');
        });
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue